# Is it permitted to upvote only to test submissions?

Tags: discussion, policy, reputation, voting, testing

In order to properly test the submissions to [Martin vs Dennis - Round 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119907/martin-vs-dennis-round-1), one would need to upvote the current lesserso their reps become equal, and then continue upvoting so the former lesser becomes the higher.

Is it permitted to vote for this reason?

Comment: A much better solution would be to use test data from a dummy API endpoint.

Answer (score 10):

## Absolutely not

#### In general

Targeted upvoting – i.e., upvoting because of the poster instead of the post itself – is forbidden on the entire network and can have unpleasant consequences both for the voter and the votee.

While going through a specific user's posts out of curiosity (and naturally upvoting several posts as a result) and going through a specific user's posts *with the intent of finding something to upvote* are very hard to distinguish for an observer, the latter is targeted voting and thus not allowed.

#### In this specific case

Answers that do not make any assumptions can be easily tested by replacing our user IDs with others'. Other answers will require a bit more tinkering, but should still remain testable by querying other SE sites apart from PPCG.

Comment: At least it doesn't count when I upvote this.

Comment: I've edited a warning into the question, feel free to edit it if necessary.

Comment: Perfect @Shaggy thanks for adding that